# How to load cudf in colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, rapids

I want to use `cudf` library in my projects and installed the rapids. It has been installed well, and here are some strings from outprint

```
Starting to prep Colab for install RAPIDS Version 0.14 stable
Checking for GPU type:
***********************************************************************
Woo! Your instance has the right kind of GPU, a 'Tesla T4'!
***********************************************************************
```

```
************************************************
Your Google Colab instance has RAPIDS installed!
************************************************
```

However when trying to `import cudf`, I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cudf'
```

I have a suggestion that it could be connected to incompatible python versions, because when running an installation script

```
# Install RAPIDS
!git clone https://github.com/rapidsai/rapidsai-csp-utils.git
!bash rapidsai-csp-utils/colab/rapids-colab.sh stable

import sys, os

dist_package_index = sys.path.index('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages')
sys.path = sys.path[:dist_package_index] + ['/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages'] + sys.path[dist_package_index:]
sys.path
exec(open('rapidsai-csp-utils/colab/update_modules.py').read(), globals())
```

I got error

```
ValueError: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages' is not in list
```

so I changed the `python3.6` to `python3.7` everywhere. Anyway, how could I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

We pushed an update last night that updates the RAPIDS install on Colab. You can run RAPIDS 0.18 and 0.19 now, as normal. It was more than just changing the paths ([check out our github if you to see the changes made](https://github.com/rapidsai/rapidsai-csp-utils/tree/main/colab)), but that was totally worth the try!  :)